Google maps api error: "The map is initialized without a valid Map ID, which will prevent use of Advanced Markers"
When I'm loading google maps with advanced markers I get the following error message.
The map is initialized without a valid Map ID, which will prevent use of Advanced Markers

What does this tell me?
I couldn't find information on this or what the "map id" is referring to.

just adding a random string when you instantiate the map works

@ProfessorAbronsius it seems like you need to set up the mapid within your google account. What happens if you choose a random string? What happens if the random string you're using is already taken by another google account?

Sure - if you are deploying a live map on a website then each site should probably have a correctly assigned map ID. For local development testing a random string seems to work fine but is probably not strictly correct

You can create a map ID by following the steps provided here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/get-map-id#create-a-map-id

To add Advance Marker, as some mentioned before, you need to already have a Google Cloud Account.
Then, you need to:

Setup map-id here is a guide.
associate that map-id with a style, here is another guide.
add the map-id to your app.

To set it, the docs says that you need to do it when you instantiate the Map object.
  // The location of Uluru
  const position = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.031 };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),  {
    zoom: 4,
    center: position,
    mapId: "DEMO_MAP_ID", // Map ID is required for advanced markers.
  });

  // The advanced marker, positioned at Uluru
  const marker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
      map,
      position: position,
      title: 'Uluru',
  });

But you also need to declare it within the HTML, like it says here
<gmp-map
  center="43.4142989,-124.2301242"
  zoom="4"
  map-id="DEMO_MAP_ID" <!-- Map ID is also required for advanced markers -->
  style="height: 400px"
>
  <gmp-advanced-marker
    position="37.4220656,-122.0840897"
    title="Mountain View, CA"
  ></gmp-advanced-marker>
</gmp-map>

Here is how it worked for me using angular's property binding, in version 18.2:
<!-- map.component.html -->

<google-maps
  [mapId]="mapId"
  ...
/>

// map.component.ts

...
export class MapComponent {
  mapId: string = 'map-id-string-generated-by-google'

  ...
}

Hope it helps.

Note: This is not referring to the API key
When you use the map, you need to specify the mapId (official documenation):
Type:  string optional
The Map ID of the map. This parameter cannot be set 
or changed after a map is instantiated. Map.DEMO_MAP_ID 
can be used to try out features that require a map ID 
but which do not require cloud enablement.

Optional seems misleading, as the mapid is required for advanced markers.
How to properly set it?
By the time of writing this post I don't know, yet. Refer to the original documentation.
